# How to fix Wordpress Font On Home Page

Tags: wordpress

Thank you advance for your response,

I'm having trouble fixing the font on this Wordpress website http://www.lacervecerianyc.com I'm using the "Restaurant" Theme.

Under "Our Menu" within the categories I noticed some letters are larger than others even though every letter is capitalized. Weird thing is everything seems fine on a mac, but not on pc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've attached an image for visual.
Kind regards[home page category font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOl2N.png)

Comment: I applied the changes suggested by @gregburkett in the style.css sheet but they don't appear when I refresh the page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Font rendering is kinda weird on some PC platforms, and that font seems to have some weird rendering issues on certain characters at specific sizes. I was able to solve the issue on my side of things by using a different font-size unit for those buttons, and tweaking that value a bit.

I changed

```
.menuitem a{font-size:12px;}
```

to:

```
.menuitem a{font-size: .83em;}
```

Maybe that'll help a bit, but you can play with that .83em value until it looks correct.

Comment: Thank you. I will apply those change.

Comment: Awesome! If you wouldn't mind, could you accept my answer as the correct one? Thanks!